# Regexp to extract data across multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

I need to capture each case definition and then the associated php filename. I've successfully got this expression to work on single line items

```
$re = 'case [\"|\'](.*?)[\"|\'].*=[\s|\"|\'](.*?\.php)';
```

The string I'm working with is:

```
 //--- the following 2 lines are captured
 case 'course_leaders'           : $page='admin/p-members/email-leaders.php'; break;
 case 'courseDifferences'        : $page='admin/p-events/diff.php'; break;

 //--- the following two cases are not processed/captured
 case 'course_leaders_report'    :
             wp_enqueue_script( 'crsLeaders'
                               , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'admin/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'
                               , array('jquery') );
             $page='admin/p-events/leaders-report.php';
             break;
 case 'course_listing'           :
             wp_enqueue_script('courseListingDataTables' //--- name
                 //--- location of js file relative to this file
                , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'admin/js/DataTables/datatables.min.js'
                , array('jquery') //--- use jquery
             );
             wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
             $page='admin/p-events/list-report.php';
             break;

 //--- this is being captured
 case 'course_program' : $page='admin/p-program/courseProgram.php'; break;
```

The course_leaders_report and the course_listing are not being captured (from regexp101.com).

```
Full match  798-866 `case 'courseDifferences'  : $page='admin/p-events/diff.php`
Group 1.    804-821 `courseDifferences`
Group 2.    843-866 `admin/p-events/diff.php`
Match 7
Full match  2036-2110   `case 'course_program' : $page='admin/p-program/courseProgram.php`
Group 1.    2042-2056   `course_program`
Group 2.    2077-2110   `admin/p-program/courseProgram.php`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP the wildcard `.` does not include newlines. So, include them yourself:

```
case [\"|\'](.*?)[\"|\'](.|\n)+?=[\s|\"|\'](.*?\.php)
```

Notice the change in the middle: `.*` to `(.|\n)+?`, making the quantifier lazy as well.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oya50Y/1)

Or as @TimBiegeleisen points out in the comments, you can add the flag `s` to run the regex in `dot all` mode:

```
/case [\"|\'](.*?)[\"|\'].+?=[\s|\"|\'](.*?\.php)/gs
```

Note that you still need to add the `?` to the quantifier to make it lazy.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJgUqd/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. Works great. One question though. The second capture group contains the 'e' from $page. Is there a way to not capture this? (If you need to spend more than 1 microsecond on it then don't worry about it) LOL

Comment: Oh, you're right. That's very weird. You can turn the middle capturing group (the one I modified) into a non-capturing group: `(?:.|\n)+?` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/J3ySIJ/2). The second example (the one with the `s` flag) doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `~case ["'](\w+)["']\s*:.*?\$page=["']([\w/-]*\.php)~s`

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SJYmdo/1))

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~                #pattern delimiter
case ["']        #match "case", a space, then a single or double quote
(\w+)            #capture group #1: greedily match one or more characters in range: A-Za-z0-9_
["']             #match single or double quote
\s*              #greedily match zero or more whitespace characters
:                #match colon
.*?              #lazily match any character (including whitespaces because of "s" pattern flag) zero or more times
\$page=["']      #match "$page=", then a single or double quote
([\w/-]*\.php)   #capture group #2: greedily match zero or more characters in range: A-Za-z0-9_/-
~                #pattern delimiter
s                #pattern modifier/flag -- makes dot also match whitespace characters
```

Vital Points:

- `[\"|\']` <- this is not the way to define the contents of a character class.  If you want to use a character class to list the two character, use `['"]`.  If you want to use alternation, you will need to use a pipe and in the context of this question, you will need to wrap alternatives in a non-capturing group to maintain pattern logic: `(?:'|")`.  The truth is: alternatives and capture groups cost "steps", so the better syntax will be a character class.
- Leveraging the posted sample data, the capture groups can contain very focused character classes. In doing so, you can use "greedy" matching.  Greedy matching outperforms Lazy matching in terms of steps.  Always endeavor to use greedy matching whenever possible.
- The `s` pattern modifier allows the dot (`.`) to also match whitespace characters.  This could be replicated with `[\s\S]`, but `.` with the `s` modifier is more brief.
- I am not sure if including `$page=` improves accuracy with your real data, but it certainly won't hurt.  From my testing, including `$page` actually improves efficiency because of the lazy dot matching before it.
- I am using NOWDOC syntax in my variable declarations so that I don't have to escape any quotes, nor take any steps to prevent parsing in the strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RiDTQ))

```
$input=<<<'INPUT'
//--- the following 2 lines are captured
 case 'course_leaders'           : \$page='admin/p-members/email-leaders.php'; break;
 case 'courseDifferences'        : \$page='admin/p-events/diff.php'; break;

 //--- the following two cases are not processed/captured
 case 'course_leaders_report'    :
             wp_enqueue_script( 'crsLeaders'
                               , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'admin/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'
                               , array('jquery') );
             $page='admin/p-events/leaders-report.php';
             break;
 case 'course_listing'           :
             wp_enqueue_script('courseListingDataTables' //--- name
                 //--- location of js file relative to this file
                , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'admin/js/DataTables/datatables.min.js'
                , array('jquery') //--- use jquery
             );
             wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
             $page='admin/p-events/list-report.php';
             break;

 //--- this is being captured
 case 'course_program' : $page='admin/p-program/courseProgram.php'; break;
INPUT;

$regex=<<<'REGEX'
~case ["'](\w+)["']\s*:.*?\$page=["']([\w/-]*\.php)~s
REGEX;

if (preg_match_all($regex, $input, $out)) {
    var_export($out);
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'case \'course_leaders\'           : \\$page=\'admin/p-members/email-leaders.php',
    1 => 'case \'courseDifferences\'        : \\$page=\'admin/p-events/diff.php',
    2 => 'case \'course_leaders_report\'    :
             wp_enqueue_script( \'crsLeaders\'
                               , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).\'admin/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js\'
                               , array(\'jquery\') );
             $page=\'admin/p-events/leaders-report.php',
    3 => 'case \'course_listing\'           :
             wp_enqueue_script(\'courseListingDataTables\' //--- name
                 //--- location of js file relative to this file
                , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).\'admin/js/DataTables/datatables.min.js\'
                , array(\'jquery\') //--- use jquery
             );
             wp_enqueue_script( \'jquery\' );
             $page=\'admin/p-events/list-report.php',
    4 => 'case \'course_program\' : $page=\'admin/p-program/courseProgram.php',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'course_leaders',
    1 => 'courseDifferences',
    2 => 'course_leaders_report',
    3 => 'course_listing',
    4 => 'course_program',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'admin/p-members/email-leaders.php',
    1 => 'admin/p-events/diff.php',
    2 => 'admin/p-events/leaders-report.php',
    3 => 'admin/p-events/list-report.php',
    4 => 'admin/p-program/courseProgram.php',
  ),
)
```